# Package management of installed system from live environment

Tags: installation, package-management, live-environment

A quick question - would appreciate a quick answer - is there a way to install packages to a system on HDD from a USB/CD/DVD live environment?

**EDIT**

Though I would love a quick answer, it doesn't necessarily have to be simple, if the only workable solution is possibly a little difficult/complicated. I'm thinking of somehow changing the target directory of `dpkg` to the hard disk instead of the live environment or something. Of course, I *don't know* how to do that or even if it's possible, hence the question. Hope my input helps me get help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to chroot into the system. Assume sda1 is your HDD:

```
sudo su
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
for f in proc sys dev ; do mount --rbind /$f /mnt/$f ; done
chroot /mnt/
```

From then on you are using the root of your HDD as root and you can `apt-get update` or `yum update` or whatever the HDD-system demands.

Exit with STRG + D or by typing `exit`.

EDIT: sometimes you seem to have to copy `/etc/resolv.conf` to your chroot as pointed out by enzotib in the comments.

Comment: Just after I executed an `apt-get` install command, the message `sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu` appeared. I hope it won't cause any problem.

Comment: Oh wait, I'm running as root, so that message appeared because I typed in `sudo` even though I didn't need to?

Comment: @Oxwivi: Start another terminal windows and `sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc`.